# WEBSOCKET Financial data, cant get the data formatted in the right way: Dictionary values python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, websocket, finance

Hey i have setup my websocket and its working great.

But i cant seem to get the data unpackked in the correct manner.

The data is a JSON dictonary, and when i try to unpack it, i get to this point.

```
[{'start': 1641475140, 'end': 1641475200, 'period': '1', 'open': 464.3, 'close': 464.8, 'high': 464.8, 'low': 464.3, 'volume': '11.62', 'turnover': '5397.945', 'confirm': False, 'cross_seq': 9713056403, 'timestamp': 1641475159431119}]
```

i use JSON.loads to unload the data, and then move in to the data by using: msg['data'] and get the above mentioned result.

Does anybody know how to reach into this block of data, makeing columns and stuff, or can anybody point me in the right direction.
I havent worked much with dictonaries before.

This is the code creating the result up top:

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    print('Message here:')
    msg = json.loads(message)
    kline = msg['data']
```

This is the full message im trying to unpack:

```
{"topic":"candle.1.BNBUSDT","data":[{"start":1641476160,"end":1641476220,"period":"1","open":464.55,"close":464.65,"high":464.7,"low":464.55,"volume":"2.83","turnover":"1315.001","confirm":false,"cross_seq":9713530932,"timestamp":1641476191430157}],"timestamp_e6":1641476191430157}
```

The data is from Bybit API

<strike>Thanks.</strike>

Best regards.

Mathias.

Comment: What do you mean by 'correct manner'? I am not sure what do you try to achieve.

Comment: Maybe you didn't notice data is a list? So to get dict content you need access specific element, like write msg["data"][0]

Comment: You are so right, thank you so much:D. 
case closed: kosciej got the answer:)

Comment: @kosciej16 i'd also suggest writeing up an answer as it might be helpful for OP to accept it

Comment: right, wasn't sure should I post an answer in such case or maybe vote for close question?

Answer (score 0):

It's because under the "data" key there is a list - it happens sometimes that even when we expect one dict it's packed in list (maybe because of some future plans). You need to access specific element of that list, so if you expect it will contain only one element, write

```
kline = msg['data'][0]
```

or treat it as normal python list of dictionaries

```
print([kline["start"] for kline in msg["data"]])
```